# Laravel hasManyThrough returns nothing

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to use the hasManyThrough relationship for first time. But when I try to call the method, It returns nothing.

Here is my database:

```
User:
- id
- (...)

Shipment:
- id
- users_id
- (...)

Shipment_question:
- id
- shipment_id
- (...)
```

And here is my model's code.

User:

```
public function Shipment()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Shipment','users_id');
}

public function Shipment_question(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Shipment_question','Shipment','users_id','shipment_id');
}
```

Shipment:

```
public function User()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User','users_id');
}

public function Shipment_question()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Shipment_question','shipment_id');
}
```

Shipment_question:

```
public function Shipment()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Shipment','shipment_id');
}
```

And here is the call:

```
Auth::User()->Shipment_question;
```

I'm using the barryvdh debugbar to see the Queries, the shipment_question call should generate a query, but in the queries log only appears the auth::user query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relations, in order to work as dynamic properties, must be `camelCased`, so rename:

```
public function Shipment_question(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Shipment_question','Shipment','users_id','shipment_id');
}

//to
public function shipmentQuestion(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Shipment_question','Shipment','users_id','shipment_id');
}
```

then you will be able to call it:

```
Auth::user()->simpmentQuestion;
```

otherwise the only way you can work with it is calling it directly as a method:

```
Auth::User()->Shipment_question()->getResults();

// what gives the same result as dynamic property after fix:
Auth::User()->shipmentQuestion;
```

**In general, Laravel4+ naming conventions force (like above, or at least suggest for other cases) using `camelCased` methods and properties and `StudlyCased` classes.**

So I suggest renaming your `Shipment_question` class to `ShipmentQuestion` as well.

Comment: Incredibly that solves the problem. I suppose that the camelCased convention was only that, a convention, not a functional aspect of laravel. Thank you.

Comment: In general it's just a convention. However in this case, when you leverage Eloquent feature, you just need to know how it works.